# JQuery UI Accordion with dynamically adding panels

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am trying to create an accordion with JQuery UI which allows users to dynamically add additional panels to the accordion. When the additional panel is added it should be opened by default. I have got most of the way, however, the last part has me tearing my hair out.

```
<div id='accordion'>
    <h4>Panel 1 Link</h4>
    <div>
        Panel 1 content goes here
    </div>
    <h4>Panel 2 Link</h4>
    <div>
        Panel 2 content goes here
    </div>
</div>
<a href='#add' id='addPanel' onclick='addPanel(3)'>Add Panel</a>
```

The Javascript

```
<script>
function addPanel(panelNo) {
        var panelContent = "<h4>Panel " + panelNo + " Link</h4><div>Panel " + panelNo +     " content goes here</div>"
             $('#accordion').append(panelContent).accordion('destroy').accordion({collapsible: true,     active: panelNo});

        var newPanelBtn = panelNo + 1;
        $('#addPanel').html("<a href='#add' id='addPanel' onclick='addPanel(" +     newPanelBtn + ")'>Add Panel</a>");
}
</script>
```

Everything is working as it should except for the fact that when a panel is added, it is open as it should be, but then when another panel is selected it does not close.

Answer (score 0):

The following tweak to the javascript that recreates your accordion should sort the issue out for you:

```
$('#accordion').append(panelContent).accordion('destroy').accordion({collapsible: true,     active: ":last"});
```